# Pytube3, how can you choose ŕesoulution of stream you want to download

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to build a YT video downloader but i have issue with selecting a specific resolution.
My code so far:

```
from pytube import YouTube

videoUrl = str(input("Enter videoUrl"))
print("Select 1 if you want to download video or select 2 to download audio only")
def downloadVideo():
    yt = YouTube(videoUrl)
    (yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).filter(res='1080p').first().download())
    print(yt.streams)
   
def downloadAudio():
    yt=YouTube(videoUrl)
    (yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download())
    print("Download finished successfully")
userChoice =int(input())
if userChoice == 1:
    downloadVideo()
   
elif userChoice == 2:
    downloadAudio()
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

after i run this i get this error:

```
 File xxx, line 17, in <module>
    downloadVideo()
  File xxx, line 8, in downloadVideo
    (yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).filter(res='1080p').first().download())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'
```

any solution for this error? I googled but could not find anything useful that would filter and worked in same time. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you get as output when you add `print(yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).all())` before the `.download()` line?

Comment: Not sure but that probably means that there aren't any streams available for that video with 1080p resolution.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks, you opened my eyes,  thing was that there was no progressive video with that resolution, removed filter and now it is working, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
for getting highest resolution of that video.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Documentation can be found here: https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/streams.html